# how to scale math font only

Tags: fonts, math-mode, scaling

I am trying to mimic our institute's PPt-template for presentation foils using the beamer-class. The corporate quidelines prescribe the use of Helvetica as the main font. However, package helvet does not provide a good mathematical font. Therefore I want to replace it with the math font from the cmbright package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%main font Helevtica
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

%prevent beamer from meddling with math fonts
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

%following lines borrowed from cmbright.sty
\DeclareSymbolFont      {operators} {OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont        {letters} {OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont      {letters}{bold} {OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont        {symbols} {OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit} {OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt} {OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{letters}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathalpha}{letters}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathalpha}{letters}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{letters}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathalpha}{letters}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathalpha}{letters}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathalpha}{letters}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{letters}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{39}
\let\upDelta\Delta
\let\upOmega\Omega
\let\upGamma\Gamma
\let\upTheta\Theta
\let\upLambda\Lambda
\let\upXi\Xi
\let\upPi\Pi
\let\upSigma\Sigma
\let\upUpsilon\Upsilon
\let\upPhi\Phi
\let\upPsi\Psi

%doesn't seem to have an effect
%\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12.5}{10}{10}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 Some Math E$E$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works quite well, except that the math letters are somewhat smaller than the normal Helvetica text. Is there a way to scale the fontsize, say by 1.1, if the typesetter is in math mode?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can try,

```
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10.5}{7}{7}
```

the format of the command is:

```
\DeclareMathSizes {t-size} {mt-size} {s-size} {ss-size}
```

Basically, we instruct the use of a  `<mt-size>` as the math text size, `<s-size>` as the script size and `<ss-size>` the scriptscript size to be used in math, when `<t-size>` is the current text size. You can adjust the parameters to suit. You can also find more information at http://tex.loria.fr/general/new/fntguide.html

You can also scale down the helvetica font if you wish

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet}
```

This is probably a better solution than scaling up the maths fonts.

When using the `\DeclareMathSizes` the first parameter for the text font must be exactly what is used in the class declaration. For example with Beamer rather declare `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}`, 
otherwise the command will appear as it is not working. It is also normal when you declare math sizes to provide a range of math font sizes for all the text fonts:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{9.8}{17}{7}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.0}{17}{7}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10}{7}{7}   % For size 10 text
\DeclareMathSizes{11}{19}{13}{9}      % For size 11 text
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{20}{14}{10}     % For size 12 text
```

You can test the above with the minimal example below, which is somewhat reduced from that originally posted:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%main font Helevtica
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

%prevent beamer from meddling with math fonts
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

%following lines borrowed from cmbright.sty
\DeclareSymbolFont      {operators} {OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont        {letters} {OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont      {letters}{bold} {OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont        {symbols} {OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit} {OT1}{cmbr}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt} {OT1}{cmtl}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbold}{OML}{cmbrm}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathalpha}{letters}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{15}

\DeclareMathSizes{9.8}{17}{7}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.0}{17}{7}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10}{7}{7}   % For size 10 text
\DeclareMathSizes{11}{19}{13}{9}      % For size 11 text
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{20}{14}{10}     % For size 12 text

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a test $ a^{2}+\gamma\sigma^{\epsilon}$

 \fontsize{9.8pt}{13pt}\selectfont
 This is a test $ a^{2}+\gamma\sigma^{\epsilon}$

%\fontsize{10pt}{13pt}\selectfont
 This is a test $ a^{2}+\gamma\sigma^{\epsilon}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yannis: I edited the example to make it a working minimal one. The \DeclareMathSizes doesn't seem to have an effect, but \usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet} works fine! Thanks a lot! (+1).

Comment: I wish I could edit my own comment. Sorry for misspelling your name.

Comment: @Alexander Please see my edit. Not to worry about the name, you can find it spelt both ways! `\textgreek{Giannis}` with babel greek option!

Comment: \DeclareMathSizes works but it enlarges the footnotes also, which now look bad. The footnote number must be programmed using math to get it as a superscript. Anyone knows how to avoid that?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides 
It would be really great if you could explain, why 10.95 works for size 10 text, please

Comment: I didn't manage to make DeclareMathSizes working for Memoir Class and 14pt, do you know if there is anything that specify it doesn't work?

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291399/beamer-how-to-change-the-font-size-in-math-mode)

Comment: Such a great suggestion,