# Larger font size in math display equation environment?

Tags: equations, fontsize

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % \scalebox
% defaults seem to be: pslatex.sty:103: \DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{9}{7}
% NB: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <16> not available, size <17.28> substituted on input line 6.
% \DeclareMathSizes{12}{17.28}{9}{7} % (a)
\begin{document}
Here I'll be trying a small example... First, I am writing an inline equation here: $a + b$; also comparing plain number 123 vs. $123$ as inline equation -- and here, below, I'm using display equation:

\begin{equation}%
% \large % (b)
% \scalebox{1.5}{ % (c)
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} %
% } % (c)
\end{equation}

... and finally, I'm having a closing sentence, just to have some text after the display equation.

\end{document}

% # convert -density 150 test.pdf -crop 846x329+196+251 test_.png
```

Now - compiled as is, the output produced is:

[image: test_01]

That is the default output, and I'd like to change (in this case, increase/make larger) *only* the display equation's - the one in the `equation` environment - font size.

So, if I uncomment only statement `(a)` (with `\DeclareMathSizes`), I get this:

[image: test_01a]

The display equation size changed, and the equation numbering didn't, which is good - but the inline equations also changed size, which I don't want.

Then, if I uncomment only statement `(b)` from the posted MWE (with `\large`), I get:

[image: test_01b]

The display equation size changed, and the inline equations didn't, which is good - but also the equation numbering changed size, which I don't want.

Finally, if I uncomment only statement `(c)` from the posted MWE (with `\scalebox` and its closure) - I cannot even compile the MWE, as it fails with:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.14 }
       % (c)
? X
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

So, how could I change *only* the math display equation font size? If there is a different approach for "case-by-case" (e.g. in individual `equation` blocks) setting, vs. a global setting (per document), that would be nice to know too.

Comment: Do you want to increase the size inside all `equation` environment through out the dcoument or is it only at some places?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @HarishKumar - I cannot exactly tell, honestly, which is why the last sentence in OP is so undecided `:)` I think I'd like to change only at some places first; then if it turns out that in the document I write, most equations seem to need this increase, then I'd like to convert the individual changes to a single, global document setting. Cheers!

Comment: Also related: [Size commands do not work in mathmode - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/size-commands-do-not-work-in-mathmode)

Comment: if the only problem were the size of the tag, this simple code replacement for `amsmath` fixes that: `\makeatletter \def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\normalsize#1}} \makeatother `. however, it's not enough, since the vertical spacing is also affected badly by the change in size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This defines a new environment `myequation` with the help of `environ` package:

```
\NewEnviron{myequation}{%
    \begin{equation}
    \scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
    \end{equation}
    }
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % \scalebox
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myequation}{%
\begin{equation}
\scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
\end{equation}
}

\begin{document}
Here I'll be trying a small example... First, I am writing an inline equation here: $a + b$; also comparing plain number 123 vs. $123$ as inline equation -- and here, below, I'm using display equation:
%% Don't leave this line empty
\begin{myequation}%
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} %
\end{myequation}
%
... and finally, I'm having a closing sentence, just to have some text after the display equation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @HarishKumar - I was thinking there is maybe some command/parameter I could change, and keep on using `equation`; but this confirms that is probably not the way to do it. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau You are welcome. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Note that math mode is turned to inline instead of displayed (as regular equations). `$\displaystyle \BODY$` fixes this.

Comment: Is there any way to only change the equation size but not the \text{..} size inside the environment?

Answer (score 6):

Just to make a note - via this answer: [Setting math font size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94232/setting-math-font-size/95688#95688); I also got this to work (`\mbox` + `\fontsize` + `\(`) with the `equation` environment (just the equation snippet here, without the rest of the MWE):

```
\begin{equation}% 
\mbox{\fontsize{17.28}{21.6}\selectfont\( %
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} %
\)} %
\end{equation}
```

Also this seems to work (`\Large` instead of `\fontsize`):

```
\begin{equation}% 
\mbox{\Large\( %
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} %
\)} %
\end{equation}
```

The important quote from there seems to be:

> ... need to switch out of math mode, use a lower level font size change such as `\fontsize` ... and then switch back into math mode using `\(` not `$` ...

Another quote that may clarify, from [How to change the size of formulas? - Wikidot Community](http://community.wikidot.com/forum/t-5373/how-to-change-the-size-of-formulas):

> You'll also note that there's some \mbox weirdness in there. The font selection command don't work in math mode ... So, we use the \mbox to create a little text-mode environment inside the equation, change the font, and declare an equation inside the text box. Sort of like Russian dolls, but it works.

(Note that the weird font sizes above are so as to avoid "*LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMX/cmex/m/n' in size <16> not available, size <17.28> substituted on input line 15.*")

Comment: What about `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\small }`. It will make all display math in \small font size including equation numbers

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `relsize`package, which has a `\mathlarger`command. If you use it in one of the amsmath environments, you have to repeat the command for each part of the formulae (not working with `&`and `\\`:

```
           \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
            \usepackage{amsmath}
            \usepackage{graphicx} %
            \usepackage{relsize}

            \begin{document}
            Here I'll be trying a small example... First, I am writing an inline equation here: $a + b$; also comparing plain number 123 vs. $123$ as inline equation -- and here, below, I'm using display equation:
            \begin{align}
            f(z)  & = a \cdot k^{z} \\%
            \mathlarger{f(z) } & = \mathlarger{a \cdot k^{z}}
            \end{align}
            ... and finally, I'm having a closing sentence, just to have some text after the display equation.

            \end{document}
```

[image]