# How to write a text under subscript

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts

I know two different ways to write the following:

[image]

We can either type `$(a_{ij})_{\mathop{1\le i\le n}\limits_{1\le j\le n }}$` or, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40217/73327), `$(a_{ij})_{\underset{1 \leq j \leq n}{1\le i\le n}}$`. The output (the picture above) is the same in both cases. Notice that 1< j < n has a smaller size than 1 < i < n. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160446/73327). So I typed `$(a_{ij})_{\mathop{1\le i\le n}\limits_{\mbox{\tiny\(1\le j\le n\)}}}$`. The result is pretty ugly:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to write it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$(a_{ij})_{\substack{1\leq i\leq n\\1\leq j\leq n}}$$
\end{document}
```

Here is the result :

[image]

All lines have the same font-size.

Please note that with `substack` your number of line is not limited.

Comment: Yes it's working well. Thank you very much!