# No command like \large \Large \Huge and so on work in my LaTeX document

Tags: math-mode, dimensions

I was trying to enlarge a bit some equations, and I tried EVERYTHING.

\large \Large \begin{large} \mathlarger..

None of those commands work. I don't know what to try. 
Does anyone have some idea?

If this help, here is my LaTeX "starting code":

```
\documentclass[danish, a4paper, 12pt]{report}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=20cm, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\graphicspath{{"Immagini/"}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{apple}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}
\definecolor{awesome}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}
\definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\de}{\text{d}}
\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

cui e chiesto un tempo $t^*$ per il quale il peso e il doppio, ossia
$$P(t^*)=2P_0$$
Si agisce come prima, solo che in questo caso l'incognita è il tempo,
e si scrive
$$2P_0 = \scalebox{2}{e^{\frac{\ln(1.4)}{30}\ t^*}}$$

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I also tried with

```
\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}
```

and nothing happens...

After having tried with "scale box" and after having failed again... here is a screenshot of the log.

[image]

Comment: No indeed, these commands apply to text, but not to mathematical equations and objects. Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/make-equations-large, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/how-to-make-math-symbols-bigger, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160437/larger-font-size-in-math-display-equation-environment, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94232/setting-math-font-size/95688#95688 All good resources

Comment: @Au101 Ah lol! That was the error! Thank you!

Comment: @Au101 First try with "scale box": failed. I'll search for other ways...

Comment: Well in that case, the best thing for you to do is rather than asking about the general case, give us an MWE which demonstrates your setup (all relevant packages, but none of the irrelevant ones ideally) and an equation to experiment with. Then it might be easier to find out why the generic methods aren't working for you and suggest the correct approach

Comment: @Au101 Edited with a screenshot. Packages and all what I used are those I wrote above. The only error lies within that row..

Comment: Thanks for adding :) Copying and pasting the code in like you did before is by far the preferred method, because then we can copy and paste it from your question, straight into a file, and start playing around. Whereas with a screenshot, we'd have to type it all out ourselves! Also, an ideal [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would not have unnecessary extra code like `\definecolor{awesome}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}` which is clearly not related to the problem

Comment: But an MWE which has too much in it is better than one which has not enough in it, so don't worry about that too much, but it will really help you get the best answers if you focus on producing good MWEs, the easier it is to help you, the better it is for you, I think :)

Comment: @Au101 Sorry for that, I thought that having all the code would have been better >.<

Comment: No worries! It's definitely better than leaving out something which does turn out to be relevant. The number of questions which get answers only for the OP to reveal that it doesn't work because they're using package `foo` is astonishing. But, still, it's definitely good to learn about minimising your examples, it can only help you, because otherwise the problem can easily be lost in loads of unnecessary code. Also if you load a non-standard package, people may even have to go to the trouble of installing it before they can even start on your problem. Clearly this doesn't help you

Comment: @Au101 You're right indeed. The fact is that everything I tried, does not work.. Even the math larger command. I clearly don't know what to do, I read lots of answer but they did not help..

Comment: LaTeX can do INCREDIBLE things with VERY SIMPLE commands.

Why has this one to be that complicated?

Comment: Whatever else you may do, remove the instruction `\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}` from the preamble. I can't possibly work; for one, `\Large` is already defined by LaTeX; hence, `\newcommand\Large{...}` must throw an error message.

Comment: @Mico I removed that line already! :D

Comment: @AlanTuring I'm not sure why you found it complicated, `\large\begin[equation}1=2\end{equation}` would make a large equation (there is some fine tuning you could do the vertical space but the equation will be large)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle .... And here we are... probably it's because I use $$ instead of begin{equation}...

Comment: @AlanTuring no `\large$$1=2$$` would be large as well (but actually I see you only wanted to make a subterm large, in which case `$$a=\mbox{\large$\sqrt{x}$}$$` would work as well. (but `$$` is not latex syntax.

Comment: @Oh, really? I learnt the $$ command from my thesis supervisor, I thought it was a super awesome command, rather than writing \begin{equation} etc every time.. lol

Comment: @AlanTuring `$$ ... $$` is a TeX command. It should not be used in LaTeX, [there are many things wrong with it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). The LaTeX shorthand is `\[ ... \]`. This is what you need to use. Note one immediate advantage, it's easy to see where it starts `\[` and where it ends `\]`. If I am looking at your source code and I see `$$` how do I know whether I am entering or leaving display math mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely not want to scale parts of the equation, but rather use the proper way of setting it.

By the way, why asking for Danish when the document appears to be in Italian?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some examples}

\section{Bad example}

Ecco una formula composta male. Si agisce come prima, solo
che ora l'incognita è il tempo, e si scrive
\[
2P_0=\scalebox{2}{$e^{\frac{\ln(1.4)}{30}\ t^*}$}
\]
Ecco la stessa formula composta correttamente. Si agisce come
prima, solo che ora l'incognita è il tempo, e si scrive
\[
2P_0=\exp\biggl(\frac{\ln(1.4)}{30}t^*\biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `$$` should ***never*** be used in LaTeX. Using `\large` or `\Large` instead of `\scalebox` would not solve the main issue, even if they worked in math mode, which they don't.

[image]

If you insist on the exponential notation, you can type

```
\[
2P_0=e^{(\ln(1.4)/30)t^*}
\]
```

to get

[image]

Two story fractions in exponents should be avoided as long as possible.

Comment: Grazie!! Molto chiaro! Effettivamente volevo tenere l'esponenziale come "e". 
P.s. Complimenti per i pacchetti che hai creato e per il manuale! :O 
tanta stima

Comment: P.s. WHy $$ shall be never used? I learnt it from my thesis professor, years ago.. I thought t was cool!

Comment: @AlanTuring [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: @AlanTuring: From your thesis advisor?  How many years ago?

Answer (score 4):

You've shown us a lengthy preamble so far but no code that actually attempts to change the math font size.

Anyway, it is entirely possible to change the font sizes used in math mode, as the following MWE demonstrates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\pyth{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
\pyth
\large\pyth
\Large\pyth
\LARGE\pyth
\huge\pyth
\Huge\pyth
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to create N newcommand for all the equations I have to write. Or am I missing something?

Comment: P.s. the math font size changer should be "scalebox" and I wrote it. And I read it comes from the graphicx package, which I use!

Comment: @AlanTuring - Yes, you are missing something: the *purpose* of the `\pyth` macro. It is certainly not necessary to define macros to contain the equations. You may verify that this assertion is true by replacing every instance of `\pyth` in the body of the text with `$a^2+b^2=c^2$` -- or any other equation you care about... -- and recompiling the code.

Comment: Uhh! Going to try! I did not know that :D

Comment: Nothing works...

Comment: The `\scalebox` can process both text mode and math mode material. I don't see any necessity for `\scalebox` here.

Comment: @AlanTuring - "Nothing works" is rather unspecific. My MWE obviously does work. I assume you're doing "something else" and that this "something else" isn't working. Sadly, I'm no clairvoyant. Unless you tell us *what* you're actually doing, the likelihood that anyone will be able to offer specific and helpful advice is going to be negligibly small.

Comment: I am doing nothing.. My preamble is that I wrote above, and what I tried now was simply your macro. But nothing changed, the formula is still small

Comment: @AlanTuring It works for me if I remove `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`. Try removing that, tell me if it works or not, and then we'll know whether the problem is there or not. Myself I do not have this font so I can't experiment

Comment: @Au101 If I remove that package, lots of other errors pop up -.- Sigh