# How can we change only text font size (not math) of all document in pdflatex?

Tags: fontsize

How can I change only the text font size (*not* math) of *all* documents in pdflatex?

(I searched for an answer without success.)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying "all documents"? (Font size is a matter of documentclasses.) Is your point maybe restricted to the issue of handling fonts differently in text and math mode?

Comment: Does the following question help: [how to scale math font only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only)

Comment: thanks for answers. what i need is like "text=13pt", "math=12pt" in a document.

Comment: In addition to @MarcoDaniel's answer, you can use `\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}` to make the body text size 13pt (with 15pt `\baselineskip`), but note that this will NOT affect heading sizes, footnote sizes, or commands like `\large`, etc.