# Force \displaystyle throughout document (including subscripts and fractions)

Tags: math-mode

How do I force `\displaystyle` to all instances inside fractions, superscripts, and subscripts throughout the entire document (including intext)?

Basically I am looking for something that effects

```
\frac{1}{\displaystyle \Big[1-\frac{q^{\displaystyle{2}}}{0.71}\Big]^{\displaystyle{2}}}
```

but without having to insert `\displaystyle` all over the code.

Is it also possible to retain `\textstyle` `\subscriptstyle` functionality to force the smaller type on certain occasions?

Comment: just use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` (amsmath package)

Comment: For what it's worth, the directives `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` are *switches* and do *not* take an argument. Instead of writing `q^{\displaystyle{2}}` you may want to write `q^{\displaystyle 2}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Using `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` won't place material in (single or double) subscripts and superscripts in `\displaystyle`, will it? (Not that I'm advocating that the OP actually do what he/she purports to want to do...)

Comment: @Mico no but it's an easy way to get the more reasonable parts of the request:-)

Comment: Try the following in your preamble: `\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\frac\dfrac \DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{10}{10} \everymath{\displaystyle}` (see [How to scale math font only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8434/5764)).