# How to use the blackboard fonts of the kpfonts package in another package

Tags: kpfonts, newtxmath

I want to use the blackboard fonts of the kpfonts package.  Also I would like to scale them. Note in the newtxmath package we have the option of scaling. So generally I scale it by "1.1" factor.

I tried looking at the boondox package which actually incorporates different blackboard fonts. But this is not helping me much.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried ` \DeclareMathSizes {t-size} {mt-size} {s-size} {ss-size}` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only)?  Or do you want to scale only a few symbols?

Comment: Just want to scale bb symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's the other way around: how to get other blackboard bold fonts instead of those provided by `kpfonts`. `;-)`

Here's a way: find out what font family contains the characters, extract the information from the `.fd` file and add the scaling feature. Don't worry, I did it for you. `;-)` Just decide what magnification factor you want instead of `1.3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{jkpsyb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpsyb}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.3] jkpsyb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpsyb}{bx}{n}{<-> s*[1.3] jkpbsyb}{}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{jkpsyb}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{bold}{U}{jkpsyb}{bx}{n}

\begin{document}

$X\mathbb{R}Y$

\boldmath $X\mathbb{R}Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer :). Em, what is this 2301 under ur 477k rep points??

Comment: @S.C. The bronze badges ;)

Comment: Oops it came in the next line so was confused ;). Thanks once again for the answer though