# define font size of math environment

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fontsize

(How) Can I define font size in math environment universally to effect equation, align or displaymath(`\[...\]`) etc, but not the inline math?
Current, I am doing as:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
Normal text
\begin{align}
F&=ma\\
E&=mc^2
\end{align}\scriptsize
Script text
\begin{align}
F&=ma\\
E&=mc^2
\end{align}
\normalsize
\end{document}
```

to put the equations in scriptsize, which is working. 
But, can I (I have my custom theme file) add this in theme file so that the change in fontsize is inbuilt?

Comment: You could modify equation, align and every other math environment you use to perform the size change.  Also, any change inside a group will revert to normal at the end of the group.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8448/36296

Comment: @samcarter : thanks for the reference. Please, do you have any idea about the ratio between normalsize to script and other sizes?

Comment: @BaRud no, you could try to search on this site.