# How to scale inline mathmode font

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, fontsize, scaling

I would like to know how to scale the size of the text on the integral limits and also the powers in the code given below:

[image]

I used the command `\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10}{7}{7}` given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only) but there was no change to the fonts.  Thanks for your help!

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

%======================================================================================
%   FONTS
%======================================================================================

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Font
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
BoldFont=Source Code Pro,
]
% Normal font
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
Numbers=OldStyle,
BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium,
ItalicFont=Fira Sans Light Italic,
BoldItalicFont=Fira Sans Medium Italic
]
% Normal font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
Numbers=OldStyle,
BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium,
ItalicFont=Fira Sans Light Italic,
BoldItalicFont=Fira Sans Medium Italic
]

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}
\begin{document}

{\textbf{Communications Systems}}\\
Z23367851
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\tiny,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\scriptsize\bfseries]

%------------ Bandwidth and Noise ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    A band limited signal cannot be time limited and a time-limited signal cannot be band limited.\\
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Bandwidth and Noise Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Bandwidth and Noise};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Energy ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        Energy $E = \int\limits_{\infty}^{-\infty}|x(t)|^{2}dt$ if $E$ is finite\\
        Power $P=\lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_{T/2}^{-T/2}|x(t)|^{2}dt$
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Energy Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Energy};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe the main issue is that you're setting the option `font=\tiny` when setting up `\tikzstyle`. The text mode command `\tiny` corresponds to  the math mode command `\scriptscriptstyle` -- that's the smallest there is. Hence, the superscript- and subscript-position symbols can't be made any smaller. Question: What's the purpose of the `font=\tiny` option?

Comment: As @Mico pointed out, the Computer Modern math font has reached its minimum designed size after `\tiny` is issued under the default class option `10pt`. Maybe you could try `\DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{4}{3}`, provided that the math font is scalable, but this will no doubt make the text/math unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `font=\tiny`, as it won't let you typeset subscript and superscript material satisfactorily. At most, use `font=\scriptsize`; this recommendation is based on the fact that your code contains only first-level subscript and superscript material. If it contained second-order subscript and superscript material, I'd omit the `font=...` option entirely.

Using `\int\limits` in inline text mode surely is a typographic abomination. Use `\int` without `\limits`, please.

It's a common mistake to load the `colortbl` and `xcolor` packages independently. Don't do it; write `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` instead.

About some of the other packages: the `amsfonts` package is loaded automatically if `amssymb` is loaded, and the `amsmath` package is loaded automatically if `mathtools` is loaded. Hence, no need to load either `amsmath` or `amsfonts` explicitly. Likewise, `fontspec` is loaded automatically by the `unicode-math` package.

The Latin Modern Math font family, which is the default math font, doesn't harmonize all that well with `Fira Sans`. Give `Asana Math` a try.

I can't figure out what employing a `multicols*` environment is supposed to achieve; the following code makes do without this environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
%%\usepackage{multicol} % doesn't seem to be needed
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
%%\usepackage{esint}  % is this needed?
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load 'colortbl' in way that maximizes compatibility with 'xcolor'

\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

%=====================================
%   FONTS
%=====================================

\usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % 'Ligatures=TeX' is the default 
% Normal font
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
     Numbers       = OldStyle,
     BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
     ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
     BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
     BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

%% Math font
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick, font=\scriptsize,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\scriptsize\bfseries]

\begin{document}
\textbf{Communications Systems}\\
Z23367851

%%\begin{multicols*}{3} %% What's the purpose of this instruction?

\bigskip
%------- Bandwidth and Noise ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
A band limited signal cannot be time limited and 
a time limited signal cannot be band limited.
\end{minipage}
};
%------- Bandwidth and Noise Header ----------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Bandwidth and Noise};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------- Energy ------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
Energy $E = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty}|x(t)|^{2}dt$ if $E$ is finite

Power $P=\lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}
   \int_{T/2}^{-T/2}\lvert x(t)\rvert^{2}dt$
\end{minipage}
};
%--------- Energy Header --------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Energy};
\end{tikzpicture}

%%\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `_{\infty}^{-\infty}` and `_{T/2}^{-T/2}` though… Perhaps add a sentence explaining why `amsfonts` is removed would be helpful to new comers. Also, I doubt the use of `esint` when other math font is used as it provides integral signs based on Computer Modern/Latin Modern.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - Thanks for these suggestions. I've added a paragraph with additional package-related observations.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - I noticed the inverted order of the lower and upper limits of integration as well. I have no idea what the OP is trying to achieve with inverting the order, but I decided not to bring it up as the issue doesn't affect typographic matters.

Comment: I'd additionally mention that `unicode-math` already includes every symbol and math alphabet in `amssymb` and `amsfonts`.  You generally will not want to combine the old NFSS symbol fonts with `unicode-math` anyway.

Comment: @Davislor - I already mention that it's not necessary to load `amsfonts` explicitly if `amssymb` is loaded. About `unicode-math`: it may provide code for all symbols defined by amssymb/amsfonts, but whether or not the symbols are actually available also depends on the Unicode math font. A somewhat limited math font such as Neo Euler does not provide all symbols natively; supplementing that font's limited list of symbols  with the offerings of amssymb/amsfonts may still be required.

Comment: @Mico That certainly works, but what I recommend (and have posted in answers here) is to load Neo Euler with the `range=` option along with a fallback math font. It's an unusual special case where the font was abandoned and not on CTAN.

Answer (score 2):

Your default math font is not correctly scaled to your main document font.  Since you are loading `fontspec` anyway, just load `unicode-math`, load a math font with `Scale=MatchUppercase` after you `\setmainfont`, and you're good to go.

The larger problem (no pun intended) is that LaTeX will not scale superscripts and subscripts down to 1.25 points.  I raised the font size of the minipages to `\footnotesize` and their width to match.

I've taken some liberties with your source here, including replacing the math letters with your text fonts.  Comment out the lines indicated if you do not want that.  You might instead try raising the font size in the package options.  I also added back in `\textstyle` for use inside an `amsmath` environment, and changed around some of the fractions.  The absolute-value bars are now left and right delimiters that stretch, and the d in d*t* is properly upright and spaced.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview, 10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}    % includes amsmath
\usepackage{xfrac}        % for \sfrac
\usepackage{unicode-math} % includes fontspec, all symbols in Unicode
\usepackage[cols, HTML, hyperref, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta}

% Normal font
  \setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium,
  ItalicFont=Fira Sans Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=Fira Sans Medium Italic,
  Ligatures={Common, Rare, TeX}
]

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}

% Normal font
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  BoldFont=Fira Sans Medium,
  ItalicFont=Fira Sans Light Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=Fira Sans Medium Italic,
  Ligatures={Common, Rare, TeX}
]

% For source code
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
  BoldFont=Source Code Pro,
  Ligatures=TeX
]

% The correctly-scaled math font
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

% Comment out if you want to keep the Latin Modern math letters.
% Alternatively, there's a Fira Math project that's a work in progress.
\setmathfont{Fira Sans Light}[range={up,\infty}]
\setmathfont{Fira Sans Medium}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{Fira Sans Light Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{Fira Sans Medium Italic}[range=bfit]

\setoperatorfont{\normalfont}

% Convenience macros:
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\dx[1]{\,\symup{d}{#1}}

\begin{document}

{\textbf{Communications Systems}}\\
Z23367851

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt,
    font=\footnotesize]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white,font=\bfseries]

%------------ Bandwidth and Noise ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    A band-limited signal cannot be time-limited and a time-limited signal cannot be band-limited.
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Bandwidth and Noise Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Bandwidth and Noise};
\end{tikzpicture}

%------------ Energy ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
      \text{Energy } E &=
        \textstyle\int\limits_{\infty}^{-\infty} \abs{x(t)}^{2}\dx{t}
        \text{ if \(E\) is finite}\\
      \text{Power } P &=
        \lim\limits_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}
        \textstyle\int\limits_{\sfrac{T}{2}}^{ \sfrac{-T}{2}} 
        \abs{x(t)}t^{2}\dx{t}
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ Energy Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Energy};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a Fira Math font under development as well, if you're interested.  If you still want to tweak the settings of the superscripts and subscripts, you can add `script-features=` and `sscript-features=` settings to the options of `\setmathfont`, including `Scale=`.