# Math-mode font size increase for document global font size above 14pt

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, scaling

I'm writing a memoir with a `\documentclass[b4paper,14pt,english,twoside]{memoir}` and was very surprised that math formulas are so small.

Then my goal is to increase math-mode font size but keep a 14pt document class.

## Totally working for 12pt

I've searched a [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only), here with the following MWE (and amplified font size increase)

Here I set a 12pt document class and increasing math mode font size with `\DeclareMathSize` is working:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,12pt,english,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % For French accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATH et TiKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{20}{14}{10}

\begin{document}
test old $\displaystyle \lambda$
    \begin{equation}
        \displaystyle a\ge b_h \iff \sum_{j:a_j\ge b_h^j}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which is totally working for `12pt memoir`:

[image]

## Doesn't work anymore for 14pt

Trying to change global font size from 12pt to a 14pt and keeping an increased math mode font size doesn't work anymore.

```
\documentclass[b4paper,14pt,english,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % For French accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATH et TiKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathSizes{14}{20}{14}{10}

\begin{document}
test old $\displaystyle \lambda$
    \begin{equation}
        \displaystyle a\ge b_h \iff \sum_{j:a_j\ge b_h^j}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`\DeclareMathSizes` doesn't work anymore, switching to a `14pt` document class:

[image]

### When it's working and when it's not

After few other tests, it seems that the command is working for any `nn pt` if `nn <= 12pt` and it doesn't work anymore for any `nn pt` if `nn >= 14pt` (with `nn` being one of the allowed sizes for memoir class).

Another test ran by @daleif showed that it's not working neither for `extarticle document class` which also provides 14pt and 17t font sizes.

Why doesn't it work anymore, when above 14pt and what solutions do I have to fix it?

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing this question? I have no idea what it is you are trying to do, and what it is you want to show us with these two MWEs.

Comment: @daleif Yes sure! Thank you for your suggestion, I've tried editing my question, is it better now?

Comment: I don't think this is related to memoir, if you switch to article and use say 100 for all four args for DeclareMathSizes nothing happens

Comment: @daleif Then it's perhaps a missunderstanding of what parameters to put into DeclareMathSizes?

Comment: I'll pass it on to people to ought to know

Comment: @daleif, thanks, I've edited my question, correcting the memoir tag and mentions :)

Comment: @daleif Actually, accordingly to the question I linked in my question, you can't set all four arguments to 100 because first one HAS to be equal to [14pt] or [12pt] in document class command, i.e. global font size of document

Comment: Ahh, didn't get that then it seems to work

Comment: Then it may finally be related to memoir?

Comment: Not sure, there should not be any difference between 14pt and 12pt for memoir. I'll dig

Comment: As far as I can see from a diff of mem12.clo and mem14.clo everything comes in matching pairs. Same number of macros. So how is DeclareMathSizes getting the default font size

Comment: @daleif I know that you are passing 12 or 14 to first arg of DeclareMathSizes, so that may be how it knows what's the default font size.

Comment: Hmm, extarticle also offers 14pt and 17pt, it does not work there either

Comment: @daleif, I've mentionned your test and you in my question :)

Comment: Fåk, it does not use 14pt when you as for 14pt, it uses `\@xivpt` which is 14.4, and then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life is never easy. You need to know the **exact** font size.
`memoir` and other classes that provides an `14pt` size class option (e.g. `extarticle`), is actually not using 14pt font size, the use `\@xivpt`, which is actually 14.4!! And `17pt` is `17.28`.

This stems from the old days when the fonts a certain sizes had to be generated. Nowadays where we have scalable fonts, things are a bit blurry, so things like this gets overlooked.

You can check the value using

```
\makeatletter
\typeout{\@xivpt}
\makeatother
```

Then

```
\DeclareMathSizes{14.4}....
```

seems to work just fine.

Perhaps better

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}....
\makeatother
```

The `\@...` macros being used can be found in the `mem<size>.clo` files that comes with `memoir`

Comment: So many thanks for you! That's the perfect answer for my question and you've been so helpful, I would have never find it by my own ;) Totally deserve my +1 and select haha

Comment: @JKHA  I never even though about the sizes of those macros. As I write above their value does from the old days. I got the explanation from the chat.