# How to achive that subscripts/superscripts are scaled with the font size in a robust command?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, robust-commands, scalebox, scalerel

I would like to use smaller fonts for the subscripts and superscripts in a user-defined LaTeX command. Do you have any ideas how to scale down the subscripts/superscripts proportionally? My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname%
    \csuse{spec@#1}%
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}
  \fi
}

\defineSpecies{hhe3+}{HHe$_3^+$}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont
\spec{hhe3+}

\end{document}
```

Here I would like to have much smaller subscript `3` and superscript `+`. A solution modifying the `\spec{}` command globally would be preferred, as I have a lot of species defined such a way. I would not switch to other 'chemistry' packages but stick to this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your question is

> I changed the text font size to be 5pt, but now the superscript and subscripts look too large; how do I change them to match?

Since you are creating the super/subscripts using math mode, you need to change the math sizes. This is [accomplished through the `\DeclareMathSizes{}{}{}{}` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8434/how-to-scale-math-font-only). In the example below I changed script size to 3pts and scriptscript size to 2pts.

(As an aside, since you didn't specify a fancy font, we are using Computer Modern, which doesn't allow arbitrary scalings; to fix that we load [`fix-cm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fix-cm?lang=en).)

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname%
    \csuse{spec@#1}%
  \else
    \GenericError{}{Undefined species `#1'}{}{}
  \fi
}

\defineSpecies{hhe3+}{HHe$_3^+$}

\DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{3}{2}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont
\spec{hhe3+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: if you use multiple different font sizes throughout your document, you may need to have a corresponding `\DeclareMathSizes` for each text size.